# Datepicker dynamic min / max dates

Tags: jquery, datepicker, uidatepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using the jQuery datepicker plugin on a site I am building. I need users to be able to pick two dates from within a specified range of dates. This is straightforward enough to do.

The problem is that the allowable range of dates changes depending on another select box (with building names in). So what I need to happen is to look up the building in a mysql database, return the min and max date allowed and use the datepicker to allow users to choose a date range within the allowable range.

On my main page, I am currently using:

```
$('#dateStartMainChart').load(url);
```

to load a php file which outputs:

```
<script> 
$(function() {
    $( "#dateEndMainChartSelect" ).datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        defaultDate: -1,
        minDate: new Date(2011,03,03),
        maxDate: +0,
            firstDay: 1,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
}); 
</script>
<input type="text" class="text" value=2011-03-04 id="dateEndMainChartSelect" align="center"/>
```

where the minDate and maxDate have been populated correctly from the mysql database. However, the result is that I just get a text box with the date in it on my main page instead of the datepicker element.

Any thoughts?

Comment: "minDate: new Date(2011,03,03) ?>)," ... where has the ?>) come from ... copy/paste error, or code error?  I'm guessing it just stripped a "<?=" out, but I may as well ask :P

Comment: That was a typo on my part, it shouldn't have been there. However, it doesn't make a difference to the problem when I run it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I finally figured this out. I initially define and use the datepicker as normal. When I need to dynamically update it, I use:

```
$.getScript('url.php', function() {updateDate(); });
```

In my case, I use this on change of a select box.

The php file that is called queries a mysql database outputs the following (using echo):

```
function updateDate() {
        $( "#dateStartMainChartSelect" ).datepicker('change',{ 
            minDate: new Date(2011,01,01),
            maxDate: new Date(2011,02,01)
        });
    }
```

You can add any of the datepicker options here that you want to change. Thanks to JasCav, I ended up looking in the right places for the solution.

Comment: Happy I got you on the right path. Glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 8):

If you want to do this, you can use the "beforeShow" attribute of datepicker to help you out. Here is a pseudo-code example.

```
// Your start and end datepickers.
$('#dateStartMainChart, #dateEndMainChartSelect').datetimepicker({
    beforeShow: customRange
});

// I can't take credit for this...website to tutorial is below.
// From: http://test.thecodecentral.com/cms/jqueryui/datepicker/
function customRange(input) {
    return { minDate: (input.id == 'dateEndMainChartSelect' ? $('#dateStartMainChart').datepicker('getDate') : null),
        maxDate: (input.id == 'dateStartMainChart' ? $('#dateEndMainChartSelect').datepicker('getDate') : null)
    };
}
```

You don't even need to look at the database directly (although, you can - adjust the fields appropriately in the customRange function). In any case, this should do what you need.

Comment: Ok, so I have tried this, and it works for dynamically limiting the range so that the end date has to be after the start date. I can't figure out how I would look at the database directly using this though? Say I want to set minDate using a SELECT query to a mysql database?

Comment: @bpmccain - You'll want to retrieve the database value using your server-side language and then compare that value to the date within the above function. In my answer, I assumed that you were populating some field from the database and just wanted to compare on the fly before the user posted back to the server.

Comment: That is what I am attempting to do, but I can't get it to work. I can retrieve the appropriate value using php, but I am unsure of how to then get that value into the above function.

Comment: @bpmccain - Well, you could share the data in URL arguments, or a cookie, or in some other way like that and grab the value with JavaScript. That's easy enough. You won't be able to share it directly (I don't think - I'm not very familiar with PHP).